# change pic in dynamic UIandroid

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android. I have an image button and I want it to change after 5sec .first I wrote params and table then call image button with the first pic then I call sleep method and change pic in that but when I run this code, the first pic doesn't show. Where is my problem?

Thanks

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams superparams =
            new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TableLayout supertable = new TableLayout(this);
    supertable.setLayoutParams(superparams);
    supertable.setOrientation(TableLayout.VERTICAL);

    TableRow table = new TableRow(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =
            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    ImageButton ib2 = new ImageButton(this);
    ib2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ib2.setLayoutParams(params);


    setContentView(supertable);
    supertable.addView(table);
    table.addView(ib2);


    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        ib2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_launcher);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sleeping the main thread is usually a bad idea as it would also freeze all the UI of the app.

You can use Handlers to achieve that without the UI freezing

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 5s
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: i should import something for use this?